# Android - Navigation drawer fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I have implemented navigation drawer in my android app. but now I want to be able to change the layout using fragments when the user clicks any list item in the navigation bar. 
Here is what I have got so far:

**XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >       
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Java File**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final String[] data ={"one","two","three"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    navList.setAdapter(adapter);
    navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
            drawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

                }
            });
            drawer.closeDrawer(navList);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Using the above code, I implemented navigation drawer in my app and I see "one", "two" and "Three" list items in the navigation drawer but nothing happens when I click on them except the drawer closes.
So, my question is :
**How do I add the fragment functionality to the above given code?**

I am beginner. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to do this by FragmentActivity.

Comment: @kishandhamat why is that?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On click have

```
  selectItem(pos);
```

Then

```
public void selectItem(int position)
{
     switch(position)
     {
          case 0:
                     // fragment1
                     // use fragment transaction and add the fragment to the container
                     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
                     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();   
                     Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
                     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                     fragmentTransaction.commit();

          break;
          case 1:
                     // fragment2
          break; 
          case 2:
                     // fragment2
          break;
     } 
}
```

Comment: should I put "selectItem(pos);" after "drawer.closeDrawer(navList);"?

Comment: @ChinmayDabke why is that you have drawee code in onclick. remove tat. only selectItem(pos) after switch case close the drawer

Comment: OK. But will it close the drawer?

Comment: @ChinmayDabke there is a example in the docs. Look at it. Download @ http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44998/discussion-between-chinmay-dabke-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 2):

use This:

```
public class MenuFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);
    addFragments(new Sample(), false, false,
            AndyConstants.CONTENT_PAGE);
     }

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragment, boolean animate,
        boolean addToBackStack, String tag) {

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    if (animate) {
         ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_from_right,
         R.anim.fragment_from_left, R.anim.fragment_from_right,
         R.anim.fragment_from_left);
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

}

For Fragment:

```
public class Sample extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, container, false);
        return view;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Need not extend `FragmentActivity`. If you are supporting navigation bar below 11 you need to use AppCompat. Need to extend `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: As per question it can easily done by FragmentActivity.

Comment: its a navigation drawer.

Answer (score 1):

After generate a `Navigation Drawer Activity` by `File->New->Activity->Navigation Drawer Activity`, here are 3 steps

**First**, go to `app_bar_main.xml` then

replace

`<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>`

by

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
```

**Second**, go to `MainActivity` -> `onNavigationItemSelected` then modify it like

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragment = CameraFragment.newInstance();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragment = GalleryFragment.newInstance();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        fragment = SlideShowFragment.newInstance();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment).commit();

    setTitle(item.getTitle());

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

**Finally**, create `Fragment` class, example a Fragment

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment{

    public static CameraFragment newInstance() {
         Bundle args = new Bundle();
         CameraFragment fragment = new CameraFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, null, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

[Demo project](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidNavigationDrawerWithFragment)

[image]