# Android navigation drawer fragment - incompatible types

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

In android studio I am attempting to open a new fragment from within my navigation drawer, using the method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059179/android-navigation-drawer-fragments)

Unfortunately i get an error with the below method:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(position==1) {
        fragment = new BlankFragment(); // This is where it fails with incompatible types
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }else{

        fragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position +1);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

As for imports I am using the support type:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

My BlankFragment class extends Fragment:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment { ... }
```

The problem is that the line: fragment = new BlankFragment(); is failing with the message:

**"Incompatible types"**

Comment: check if you are using v4.Fragment version in all your classes.

Comment: Post your LogCat please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in BlankFragment?

Otherwise you are trying to add a regular Fragment to the SupportFragmentManager. I did this mistake many times, and it was hard to find in the beginning.

Comment: Apparently that was the issue.
Thank you